# Connecting Spring api REST container with MySQL container using docker compose

Tags: java, mysql, spring, docker, containers

Using some guidance from internet, repositories from github, tutorials and whatnot, i'm trying to run an app using the react-spring-mysql stack. From what i understand the mysql container it's refusing the connections, but i don't know why.

This is my application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${DB_HOSTNAME}:${DB_PORT}/${DB_DATABASE}?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=${DB_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password=${DB_PASSWORD}
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop

spring.datasource.max-wait=20000
spring.datasource.max-active=50
spring.datasource.max-idle=20
spring.datasource.min-idle=15
spring.datasource.max_allowed_packet=33554432

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=50MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=50MB
```

This is the Dockerfile in the root of the spring project:

```
FROM maven:3.9-eclipse-temurin-17-alpine as build

WORKDIR /app

COPY pom.xml ./

COPY src src/

RUN mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true

# Run the app in a minimal java container

FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jre-alpine

VOLUME /tmp

EXPOSE 8080

ARG JAR_FILE=/app/target/*.jar

COPY --from=build ${JAR_FILE} app.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

This is my docker-compose:

```yaml
services:
  airclone_mysql:
    image: mysql:8.2
    container_name: airclone_mysql
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=airclone1
      - MYSQL_USER=airclone
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=airclone1
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=airclone
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: mysql-data
        target: /var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - localnet

  airclone_backend:
    depends_on:
      - airclone_mysql
    container_name: airclone_backend
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - DB_HOSTNAME=airclone_mysql
      - DB_PORT=3307
      - DB_USERNAME=airclone
      - DB_PASSWORD=airclone1
      - DB_DATABASE=airclone
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - localnet

  airclone_frontend:
    depends_on:
      - airclone_backend
    container_name: airclone_frontend
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5173:5173"
    networks:
      - localnet

volumes:
  mysql-data:

networks:
  localnet:
    driver: bridge
```

What i'm missing?

The last part of the error in the log of the container says:

```java
2023-12-12 16:50:55 Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
2023-12-12 16:50:55 The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
2023-12-12 16:50:55     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
2023-12-12 16:50:55     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2023-12-12 16:50:55     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2023-12-12 16:50:55     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2023-12-12 16:50:55     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2023-12-12 16:50:55     at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:62) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.1.0.jar!/:8.1.0]
2023-12-12 16:50:55     at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.1.0.jar!/:8.1.0]
2023-12-12 16:50:55     at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:150) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.1.0.jar!/:8.1.0]
2023-12-12 16:50:55     at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:166) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.1.0.jar!/:8.1.0]
2023-12-12 16:50:55     at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:89) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.1.0.jar!/:8.1.0]
2023-12-12 16:50:55     at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:121) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.1.0.jar!/:8.1.0]
2023-12-12 16:50:55     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:833) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.1.0.jar!/:8.1.0]
2023-12-12 16:50:55     ... 156 common frames omitted
2023-12-12 16:50:55 Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
2023-12-12 16:50:55     at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
2023-12-12 16:50:55     at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2023-12-12 16:50:55     at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2023-12-12 16:50:55     at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2023-12-12 16:50:55     at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2023-12-12 16:50:55     at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2023-12-12 16:50:55     at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:153) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.1.0.jar!/:8.1.0]
2023-12-12 16:50:55     at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.1.0.jar!/:8.1.0]
2023-12-12 16:50:55     ... 158 common frames omitted
```

Comment: The standard MySQL port is 3306, and you need to set `DB_PORT=3306`.  Connections between containers don't use or require `ports:`.

Comment: deleted:
 ports:
      - 3307:3306
and
 ports:
      - "8080:8080"

changed:
- DB_PORT=3306

But didn't work, same error, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Ensuring Backend Starts After MySQL in Docker Compose**

It seems like your backend server might be attempting to start before the MySQL service is fully up and running. To address this issue and ensure that your backend starts only after MySQL is ready, you can leverage the `healthcheck` directive in your Docker Compose file.

Below is an example Docker Compose file demonstrating how to use health checks for MySQL and ensure that the backend service starts only when MySQL is healthy:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: mysql_container
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: your_root_password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: your_database
      MYSQL_USER: your_user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: your_password
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    healthcheck:
      test: mysqladmin ping -h 127.0.0.1 -u $$MYSQL_USER --password=$$MYSQL_PASSWORD
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3

  backend:
    image: your_backend_image
    container_name: backend_container
    depends_on:
      mysql:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

In this configuration:

- The `healthcheck` directive is used for the MySQL service. It periodically checks if the MySQL server is responsive or not.
- The `backend` service has a `depends_on` directive, specifying that it depends on the `mysql` service. This ensures that the backend service won't start until the MySQL service is healthy.

Adjust the values in the `environment` section of the MySQL service according to your specific MySQL configuration.

By incorporating these health checks, you can mitigate issues related to the backend starting before the MySQL service is ready, ensuring a more reliable setup.

I hope this helps! If you have further questions or encounter any issues, feel free to ask.

Comment: If this is in fact the problem, please flag this as a duplicate of [Docker Compose wait for container X before starting Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746182/docker-compose-wait-for-container-x-before-starting-y).  It's not totally obvious that's the problem, though.